# C# Windows Form -DataGrid -DataPropertyName

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the use of DataPropertyName in Win Form of VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx)

> Gets or sets the name of the data
>   source property or database column to
>   which the DataGridViewColumn is bound.
>
> When the AutoGenerateColumns property
>   is set to true, each column
>   automatically sets its
>   DataPropertyName property to the name
>   of a property or database column in
>   the data source specified by the
>   DataSource property. This binding can
>   also be performed manually, which is
>   useful when you want to display only a
>   subset of the properties or database
>   columns available in the data source.
>   In such cases, set the
>   AutoGenerateColumns property to false,
>   and then manually add each
>   DataGridViewColumn, setting the value
>   of each DataPropertyName property to
>   the properties or database columns in
>   the data source that you want to
>   display.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=DataPropertyName+DataGridView

See [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Dev Q&A : DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163669.aspx)

> DataPropertyName to identify if the
>   column is bound and what field it is
>   bound to.